# How can I do `$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')` in vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I don't have jQuery and I want to know how can I do the same thing with vanilla javascript. Any help?

```
$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript.

Comment: jQuery isn't vanilla JavaScript ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');
```

That's how you do it.

Answer (score 8):

`meta` elements actually have [a `content` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMetaElement), so you can simply write:

```
document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').content
```

### Demo:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').content
)
```

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="example-content"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `getElementsByName`

`document.getElementsByName('csrf-token')[0].getAttribute('content')`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method to get the element and use [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method to get the attribute value from the element.

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
```